# What does this mean: "constructor(...[configuration])?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In the [aws-sdk-js-v3](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/blob/main/clients/client-cognito-identity/src/CognitoIdentityClient.ts) I have the class CognitoIdentityClient with a constructor which expects a parameter, which I don't understand:

```
export class CognitoIdentityClient extends __Client<
  __HttpHandlerOptions,
  ServiceInputTypes,
  ServiceOutputTypes,
  CognitoIdentityClientResolvedConfig
> {
  constructor(...[configuration]: __CheckOptionalClientConfig<CognitoIdentityClientConfig>) {
    const _config_0 = __getRuntimeConfig(configuration || {});
    [...]
    }
}
```

Why these 3 dots and the brackets? What does it mean?
I'm calling it currently like this, but it leads to unexpected behaviour:

```
new CognitoIdentityClient([myConfiguration]);
```

I tried it with my own version, but can't get it to work:

```
test(...[myArgument]: string): void {
}
const myString: string = 'abc';
test(myString); //  Argument of type '[string]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
test([myString]); // Argument of type '[string[]]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
test(...myString); // Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'
```

Comment: @isherwood https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters it's the same piece of syntax either way but the meaning is different depending on context

Comment: @isherwood the reference is the dupes you linked. They were about spreading. And a couple even described rest parameters. There is no spreading happening which should be evident from this being a definition of parameters.

Comment: @isherwood RE: confusion the `...` in certain expressions (e.g. function call, array literal) *spreads* the elements of the array into positional spots. But when used to define the signature of a function instead of *spreading* an array into positional elements it instead does the, opposite: it *gathers* the positional elements *into* an array. FWIW I know you know that but it's counter-intuitive enough to have one piece of syntax do opposite operations depending on context lets not pour more fuel on the fire by linking them the wrong dupe.

Comment: @isherwood *spreading* is about taking some packed data and metaphorically spreading it. E.g., `[ ...arr ]` spreads `arr` into another array, `{ ...obj }` will spread the content of an object into another object. But rest parameters is just varargs. It does the opposite and *packs* everything together `fn = (...args) => {}` can be called with `fn()` or `fn(1)` or `fn(1, 2)` or `fn(1, 2, 3)` and all of the arguments will be put into `args`. While something like `fn = (x, ...rest)` will collect everything except the first parameter together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(...[arg]: string[]) {
    console.log(arg);
  }
}
```

Now it's clear that it equals to:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(...rest: string[]) {
    let [arg] = rest;
    console.log(arg);
  }
}
```

A mix of [Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).